# Is it possible to train a model on a more complicated data set and then retrain on a simpler dataset that has continuous frames for LSTM model?

Tags: keras, cnn, lstm, object-detection

I'm attempting to do lane detection using CNN-LSTM architectures on the TuSimple dataset. However the TuSimple data set isn't very difficult and the results are sometimes poor (visually). I want to train the model on a more difficult dataset such as CuLane or BDD initially but then use TuSimple for the LSTM section as it is the only dataset that has all of its data in continuous frame format.

How would I go about doing this? I have already trained the model on TuSimple for just CNN encoder.